# Hiding Edit menu item in Access

Tags: ms-access

How can you hide the top menu item labeled "Edit" inside an Acccess application?

Thanks

Don

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a custom toolbar to be used by your application (pre-2007), one that omits the Edit option.  In 2007, you would do this by making a custom ribbon for your application, again - omitting the Edit option